# Facebook App domain work with localhost and don't work with my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to add a Facebook sign in button to my website

What I've done so far is adding a Facebook app (type website) and choosing `http://localhost/loginFB` as path.

The app domain is the host of that site and is `localhost`

This all works great, but when I change my website to `www.example.com/loginFB`, and the app domain to `www.example.com`, I get below error if I try to sign in

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: If I remember correctly localhost is always allowed no matter what is set as the app domain. Are you sure you checked all the urls on https://developers.facebook.com/apps?

Comment: @rpi can you give me more information sir ?

Comment: there should be at least three fields with URLS inside them:
"Valid OAuth redirect URLS", "App domains" and "Site URL"

The first two are required for a Facebook app to properly redirect (assuming you are using oAuth which is not stated in the question; please expand your question so it is clearer to everyone)

Comment: @rpi on "Valid OAuth redirect URLS" how I need to make the URL with https ? that I need to make my URL here "Deauthorize Callback URL" and "Data Deletion Request URL" and "Redirect URI to Check", finally that I need to make url with /loginFB in the last ?

Comment: "Deauthorize Callback URL" is used to sign a user out on your website if the user does the same on facebook.com

"Data Deletion Request URL" is some new GDPR privacy thing where Facebook sends requests to about deleting user data if a user deletes permission for your app to access their data

I'm not sure what the latter does as I haven't been using Facebook sign in for a while

You can add https to your site by buying an SSL certificate (or for free with Letsencrypt) and installing that on your server (probably Apache or something like that if you are hosting it yourself)